# How can I make any label's color change, without repeating the same color change line for each label?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form with 3 labels drawn on.

And I have this code

```
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //drawn 3 labels.

            List<Label> lstlabels = new List<Label>() { label1, label2, label3 };

            int cnt = lstlabels.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++) lstlabels[i].Click += (object se, EventArgs ee) => { if (this.BackColor == SystemColors.Control) this.BackColor = Color.Yellow; };

        }
```

It doesn't do what I want it to do.. and I know why, but I don't know how to make it do what I want it to do.

What I would like, is that when I click a label, it goes yellow.

What the code is doing, is that when I click a label, the whole form goes yellow.

I know why it's doing that. It's doing that because 'this' is referring to the form rather than the label that was clicked.

I would like to change 'this' to something that refers to the label that was clicked.  Like not necessarily change 'this', but use something else instead of this, that would do that,  but I have no idea how.

I can try changing 'this' to lstlabels[i] but that won't work either.. I understand why that won't work either..  it gives an index out of range error. I understand why. I know that at the time a label is clicked, i==3 and so i is  out of bounds and gives no indication of what label was clicked.  So I just don't know how to do this.

I could do

```
    label1.Click += (object se, EventArgs ee) => { if (label1.BackColor == SystemColors.Control) label1.BackColor = Color.Yellow; };
    label2.Click += (object se, EventArgs ee) => { if (label2.BackColor == SystemColors.Control) label2.BackColor = Color.Yellow; };
    label3.Click += (object se, EventArgs ee) => { if (label3.BackColor == SystemColors.Control) label3.BackColor = Color.Yellow; };
```

or

```
        lstlabels[0].Click += (object se, EventArgs ee) => { if (label1.BackColor == SystemColors.Control) label1.BackColor = Color.Yellow; };
        lstlabels[1].Click += (object se, EventArgs ee) => { if (label2.BackColor == SystemColors.Control) label2.BackColor = Color.Yellow; };
        lstlabels[2].Click += (object se, EventArgs ee) => { if (label3.BackColor == SystemColors.Control) label3.BackColor = Color.Yellow; };
```

And if there are 25 labels then 25 lines like that..

But I guess that it should really be one or two lines.

And the labels might not be label1 and label2 and label3, they might be lblBob, lblJohn,  lblAndy

I think it should really be one or two lines.. and not more lines when more labels, but i'm not sure how 'cos I can't see how to do it in a loop!

Comment: The first parameter (`se`) is the sender. Use `Label source = sa as Label; source.BackColor = Color.Yellow;`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp it works. amazing! I was thinking i'd have to use reflection which would be a bit of a study. Post that solution you just gave as an answer and i'll accept it

Comment: Also MouseDown reacts much faster than Click.  `for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++) lstlabels[i].MouseDown += (object se, MouseEventArgs ee) => { Label blah = se as Label; if (blah.BackColor == SystemColors.Control) blah.BackColor = Color.Yellow; else blah.BackColor = SystemColors.Control; };`

Comment: If the list of labels is only used to connect click event handler, then I would use a single event connected at design time as in akali93 answer. But obviously in a real application, it would be very weird to change the color once on first click only...

Comment: @Phil1970 nobody, including me in my question, and any comments anybody made,  has suggested anything other than a single event connected at design time. It works for my application which is 20 labels and the ability to click them in such a way that it toggles their backgroudn colour.  So on mousedown if they're yellow make them grey and if they're grey make them yellow(which this method works for). One event (MouseDown). What did you have in mind that wouldn't apply so much in a 'real application'?

Comment: @barlop Your code only set the color to yellow and never to grey... thus the code is too complex if you do just that (and I don't see the purpose of such application). However, if your application does something else, then it might affect the solution we would use. Relying on hard-coded color is also fragile as your application would not work properly if you set the form background color to yellow or if the color are customizable by the end user so in practice one would probably have some internal data in a real application to be less fragile.

Comment: @Phil1970  yeah actually my actual code is to toggle it between grey and yellow.I just simplified it to give an example showing my actual problem rather than actual code,and my actual problem was the 'this', and yeah my simplification still had a somewhat superfluous part in the logic.  I left it there in the demonstration example 'cos it was just another instance of 'this' that I wanted to change. Re hardcoding, I wouldn't call it hardcoding the color if i'm using a constant identifier.. but yeah if it were customizable by the user then i'd be testing a variable, though it's not so it's fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, for convenience, create a seperate method for the event.
Second, when you use the keyword `this` you refer to the form, and not to the sender label. In our new method, the `sender` argument is that label.
Also, if taht's all your code is supposed to do, there is no need to check the current background color.

```
private void Label_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Label clickedLabel = (Label)sender;
     clickedLabel.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
}
```

Comment: thanks.. johnny mopp beat you to it in comment before you,   though I like your use of (Label) rather than 'as',   it look a bit more familiar and is good to know both ways.. I think he won't post his comment as an answer so i'll accept yours and if he does then i'll switch it to his.  I'd also note that lambda notation is fine.. this line worked  `for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++) lstlabels[i].Click += (object se, EventArgs ee) => { Label blah = se as Label; if (blah.BackColor == SystemColors.Control) blah.BackColor = Color.Yellow; else blah.BackColor = SystemColors.Control; };`

Comment: and yeah could've done `for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++) lstlabels[i].Click += FunctionChangeColorOnClick;`     The key was casting sender and then that providing the BackColor property.  Whether casted with (Label) or with the `as` keyword.